# Failed to read the 'Nonce' cookie for site '': Cookie named 'Nonce' was not found

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a web site(ASP.NET MVC) deployed as Azure App Services, which has the builtin Azure AD configured. like below image

[image]
Most of the my azure ad users can visit the site without any issue. but a very few number of them are running into errors. In app service's application logging(in azure storage). There are errors. Failed to read the 'Nonce' cookie for site '***.azurewebsites.net': Nonce expired on 2018-05-07T14:07:00.0000000,

Does anyone know, what's happening here? and how can i fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Similar issue has been discussed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55205325-88f1-4e3c-8b44-86d9bb73eb1a/issue-with-app-service-authentication?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). See if it helps.